# Is there a "map:" URI prefix to launch map application? (like mailto: or tel:)

Tags: dictionary, uri, mailto, url-scheme, tel

Is there such prefix for launching map application on phones,

```
<a href="map:21st,High Street, London">Toto's home</a>
```

like can do

```
<a href="mailto:toto@gmail.com">Toto's mail</a>
```

Comment: Ah, getting my terms confused. The correct term for this is [URI schema name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme) (or sometimes just "protocol").

Comment: `geo:` is the generic one, if Android and Google Maps is your main target, simply adding a link to google maps will do the trick even better e.g. setting up a track: `https://www.google.com/maps/dir//URLENCODEDADDRESS` (empty part (`//`) indicates starting point is your current destination)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`geo:` is an officially-recognised URI scheme, and `maps:` may be implemented in some clients.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo_URI_scheme

Comment: It would be interesting to have some form of "works here" list... even if very vague, but showing if usage is practical or not.

Comment: `maps:q=...` works in Safari on the iPad and starts the maps app.

Comment: geo: works on Android, maps: or maps:q= don't thx, it would be perfect if it could launch maps.google on desktop browser though

Comment: finally it's more efficient with http://maps.google.com?q= , supported on desktop and can do geocoding

Comment: `maps:` is also supported on Windows 10 in the (Bing) Maps app.

Comment: `maps:q=` works on osx and ios, I didn't get it working on windows/android. I couldn't get `geo:` to work.

Answer (score 8):

In each planform:

### Apple

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html)

Example: `<a href="http://maps.apple.com/?ll=12.34567,8.90123">`

### Android:

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Maps)

Example: `<a href="geo:40.726966,-74.006076">`

### Windows Phone:

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj635237.aspx)

Example: `<a href="bingmaps:?cp=40.726966~-74.006076">`

Answer (score 7):

Both of the previous answers are correct in their own way but did not provide a succinct example.. So here goes:

Use:

```
  <a href="geo://?q=My+address+here">View On Map</a>
```

Works on Android & Apple in my tests.

Comment: 2022; works fine on Android!

Answer (score 4):

I don't have enough of a reputation to add a comment to [ryan knell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1573153/ryan-knell)'s answer above but, having recently [implemented a geo uri feature](https://github.com/openstreetmap/openstreetmap-website/pull/994) into the **Share** panel of the [OpenStreetMap site](http://www.openstreetmap.org), I'd like to point out that there's no "//" in that scheme. It's spelled out quite clearly, with examples, in [RFC 5870](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5870).

Answer (score 4):

Apple uses link with the `maps://` protocol now too, as far as I know, only Apple Maps supports it (tested on Mac OSX 10.11 El Captain).

Example: `maps://maps.apple.com/maps?daddr=48.851925,2.337141`

So, to list them all, there are the protocols: `geo:`, `bingmaps:`, `maps:`, or linking to the various websites, eg: https://goo.gl/maps/VZG3rV6cRGE2.

Comment: `maps:` is supported by the Bing Maps app (on Windows, at least), too.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply do this...

```
<a href="http://maps.apple.com/?q=123+Main+etc...">View on map</a>
```

If the browser is on iOS/Mac, the native maps app will launch (doesn't matter the browser). If on android/windows/other, maps.apple.com will redirect to maps.google.com

Docs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007894-SW1

Comment: In my testing this takes us to a web version of the maps app - It does not launch the native maps application.

Comment: The link worked for me on iOS 15.3 - it opened the native maps app.