# as3 flex air How to access GPS "to" textbox

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I want to make a button where, when pushed, the user's native gps application opens up with the address already put in for the "to" field.

I can do something similar with the telephone dialer this way:

```
// ---------------------- CALL SOMEONE! ------------
const callURL:String="tel:6094329861";  
var targetURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(callURL);
navigateToURL(targetURL);
// ------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769631/is-there-a-map-uri-prefix-to-launch-map-application-like-mailto-or-tel

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by navigateToURL() and the user will be asked if he wants to open in broweser or app.

```
var long:Number = destinationLong;
var lat:Number = destinationLat;
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://maps.google.com/?q="+String(lat)+","+String(long)));
```