# Is there a generic map protocol for use in HTML / web-based apps

Tags: html, google-maps, cordova, hyperlink

When I want to invoke a phone dialler I use `<a href="+442088887777">Call me</a>` - and this will automatically invoke whatever the user's most appropriate application is with that number.

Is there an equivalent for maps? Something like `<a href="map:lat=51.527141,lon=-0.087853">Here I am</a>`

I know that Apple hijacks maps.google.com links to open in Apple Maps - but I wondered if there was a better way?

Comment: Thanks @velox - once I had the answer (geo:) this led me to all the answers :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10769676/1178052 which states that `geo:` is the correct uri protocol, but `maps:` may be supported in future.