# angular js maps call: url failed to load webpage the url can't be shown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, maps, ionic-framework

I'm trying to make a maps call from my ionic framework app. In my html file I use:

```
<a ng-href="maps://?q={{dest.Latitude}},{{dest.Longitude}}">Maps</a>
<div>{{dest.Latitude}},{{dest.Longitude}}</div>
```

In my controller the data for `dest` looks like this:

```
{"Latitude":12.34567, "Longitude":1.23456}
```

The latitude and longitude are shown in the div correctly.

But I get an error if I click on the link:

```
Failed to load webpage with error: The URL can't be shown
```

I also tried to cast the lat and long to string but it had no effect on it.

If I use static geocordinates like this everything works fine:

```
<a ng-href="maps://?q=12.34567,1.23456">Maps</a>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10769676/1178052 answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `map` in to href Sanitization white list.

example code:

```js
angular.module('app',[])
.config(
    function( $compileProvider ){   
        $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|chrome-extension|map|geo|skype):/);
    }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
    <a ng-href="map:lat=51.527141,lon=-0.087853">Map</a>
    <a ng-href="skype:username">Skype</a>
</div>
```

**[CompileProvider Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$compileProvider)**

Comment: If I use the $compileProvider sanitization I cant even go to the details view. It also gives me a  error "Failed to load webpage with error: The URL can't be shown" if I try to got the the details view.

Comment: I tested it in iPhone emulator and its working fine. can you tell little bit more about where and how its failing ?

Answer (score 1):

Well the compileProvider solution didn't worked for me so I made a workaround.

In my controller I use:

```
$scope.navigate = function(){
    var geoString = 'maps://?q='+dest.Latitude+','+dest.Longitude+'';
    window.open(geoString, '_system');
  };
```

And I'm calling the function like here:

```
<button ng-click="navigate()" class="button button-icon ion-earth"></button>
```

This works. I think there is a problem with data binding in the href.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, are testing it on a iOS device?
If I'm not mistaken the maps:// protocol only works on iOS with Apple Maps.

Comment: Yes its a ios device.

Comment: I edited my post. If I use the link in static way it works but not with databindings.

Comment: if I replace it like you suggested it opens google maps and not the native maps app. But I want to open the native maps app.

Comment: Strange, on my iPhone it opened the native app.
A better solution would be jad-panda's. You sanitize the map URI so ng-href should work.

Comment: Well I just can't understand why it working with static coordinates and not with the databinding.